# Dynamic Amount of EditText Preferences on Android

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am looking for a way to create a dynamic amount of `EditTextPreference`s.

I am currently creating a preference activity extending `PreferenceActivity` and creating all buttons and such in XML.

My problem is that I have a second Preference screen where I want the user to set up a new "team".

This by first selecting how many members does the team have (maybe a list Preference or another text preference) and for each member two `EditTextPreference`s appear (name and ID).

But I can't seem to find a way how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'll need to get the number of EditTextPreferences you want, and then add them all to a new LinearLayout. Something like this maybe

```
LinearLayout parent = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.PUTLAYOUTNAMEHERE));
for (int i=0; i<NUMEDITTEXTPREFERENCES; i++)
{
    EditTextPreferences newView = new EditTextPreferences(this); //Must be written inside an activity.
    parent.addView(newView);
}
```

Comment: Looks good to use something like that but i get the following error:
The method addView(View) in the type ViewGroup is not applicable for the arguments (EditTextPreference)

Comment: Well, since you cant modify an XML file, there's only one other way according to [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html), Use a  [PreferenceScreen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html). Try using the addPreference method. Hope this helps.